# Why can't the Visual Studio installer always find any local Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ide

I can’t update or uninstall [Visual Studio 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2022) if the installer can’t find Visual Studio 2022.

I have met the situation twice and even tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2022.
But I really don’t want to reinstall Windows 10.

How can I fix this?

[image: No found instance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve got the answer from the Visual Studio developer community. Here is the way:

[image]

Comment: Please add the content of the image as text.